# making a trendline in log-log scale scatter graph

Tags: matlab, trendline

I am coding to make a trendline on my scatter plot.

```
data=[];
for k=1:100
    int=0;
    for t=1:100
        if k_star_90(k,t)~=0
            int=int+k_star_90(k,t);
        end
        if k_star_90(k,t)==0 && int~=0
            data=[data int];
            int=0;
        end
    end
end

intervals = linspace(0, 1, 100); 
h1 = histc(data, intervals); 
scatter(intervals, h1, 'r');
set(gca,'xscale','log')
set(gca,'yscale','log')
```

[picture of plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuZnE.jpg)

This is in log-log scale. On this plot, I want to draw y=ax+b(1st order) trendline. I am not sure how to do it.

I will really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your intention correctly, but if you need a trend line you may do something like this

```
intervals = [0.01  0.02 0.2 0.1 0.3 0.5 0.03 0.4 0.15 0.2 0.2 0.25 1 0.9 0.8 0.8 0.7];
h1 =        [70    40   4   20  2   3   60   10  50   40  10  20   1 2   3   1   2] ;

coeffs = polyfit(intervals, h1, 1);
xFitting = 0:0.01:1;
yFitted = polyval(coeffs, xFitting);

scatter(intervals, h1, 'r');
set(gca,'xscale','log');
set(gca,'yscale','log');
grid on;
hold on;
plot(xFitting, yFitted, 'b', 'LineWidth', 2);
hold off;
ylim([1 80]);

xlabel('intervals');
ylabel('h1');
```

Here is your trend in Log scale:
[image]

Og course it does not look like a first order trend. To depict it as a line you need to go back to a normal plot:

[image]